# How to write an sql query that calculate sales monthly for a particular year?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contain a record from 2017-2021. But I need an sql code to calculate sales monthly for just 2017 alone.

It's a two different table I'm trying to call in the coding

```
SELECT sum(itemPrice) From article,
            Month(TransactionDate) FROM transactionid WHERE 
               year(TransactionDate) = 2017 group by 1
```

Comment: Please add your table structure along with some sample data.

Comment: ...and show what you've tried, even if it is only partially complete. You'll need something like `select month(my_date_col), sum(amount) from my_table where year(my_date_col) = 2017 group by 1`

Comment: I have edited my question and included code. Please help thanks.

Comment: @SegunGiver , please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE article` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE transactionid` then post the results into your question. Don't forget to indicate which column in both tables that have a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query properly, it looks like you have 2 tables called `article` and `transactionid`. I assume these 2 tables have a relationship together which I called `article_id` in the example below.

This would be pretty close to what you need, you just need set the correct column names:

```
SELECT MONTH(TransactionDate) as month, SUM(itemPrice) as total_sales
FROM article
JOIN transactionid ON transactionid.article_id = article.id
WHERE YEAR(TransactionDate) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(TransactionDate)
ORDER BY month;
```